# How to configure react-router v3 with plain route definitions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get plain route definitions working with react-router v3, but as you can see from [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6ypo95m86r) none of the components are loading.

Here's the code:

```
import Home from "/components/Home";
import About from "/components/About"; 

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Router history={hashHistory} children={this.props.routes} />;
  }
}

let routes = {
  path: "/",
  childRoutes: [Home, About]
};

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App routes={routes} />, root);
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Here are the packages I'm using (and their versions):

```
"react": "^15.6.2",
"react-dom": "^15.6.2",
"react-router": "^3.0.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first, imports on the top are not correct. You should use `relative` path to include components.
The second, to define a Routes structure you should use `<Route />` component.

Here I made some changes to your code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { hashHistory, Router, Route } from "react-router";

// components
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { routes } = this.props;

    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        {routes.childRoutes.map(({ Component, path }) => (
          <Route key={path} component={Component} path={path} />
        ))}
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

let routes = {
  path: "/",
  childRoutes: [
    {
      Component: Home,
      path: "home"
    },
    {
      Component: About,
      path: "about"
    }
  ]
};

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App routes={routes} />, root);
```

Link to the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/6lvmry9pqk.

The pages:
https://6lvmry9pqk.codesandbox.io/#/home
https://6lvmry9pqk.codesandbox.io/#/about

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ivan for the answer!

Turns out the documentation does explain [how to do it](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#configuration-with-plain-routes) and does it without using `.map()`. Here's the updated code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { hashHistory, Router, Route, Link } from "react-router";

// components
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";

const App = ({children}) => (
  <div>{children}</div>
)

const routes = {
  path: "/",
  component: App,
  indexRoute: { component: Home },
  childRoutes: [{ path: "about", component: About }]
};

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes} />, document.body)
```

[Updated Codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/o486k9wzx9)